# update multiple columns from subquery select statement sql server

Tags: sql-server

```
UPDATE [STAGING_DB_B1].dbo.tempitem
SET newitem = 'Y'
WHERE itemcode COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = * * (
        SELECT DISTINCT n0.itemcode
        FROM [STAGING_DB_B1].dbo.tempitem N0
        WHERE n0.Ordertype = 'SO'
            AND n0.filename = 'SO-TEST1'
            AND DBName = 'DB08TEXG_2'
            AND NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT R0.Itemcode
                FROM DB08TEXG_2.dbo.OITM R0
                WHERE n0.ItemCode = R0.itemcode
                )
        )
```

Subquery returns more than one value error. How do i solve it?

Comment: The subquery must return only one row. Otherwise you'll get that error. Quick and dirty solution: use `select distinct TOP 1 n0.itemcode from...`

Comment: Why don't you use IN instead of =?